# How to incorporate conditions in where clause using CASE statements in cursor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to incorporate conditions in where clause using CASE statements in the cursor. I have defined `V_CATEGORY=11` in the declare statements. So, based on the defined category it has to take the where conditions.

```
DECLARE
    V_NODE_ID  VARCHAR2(20);
    V_CATEGORY VARCHAR2(20) :=11;
    CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT isbn FROM GT_ADD_ISBNS GT;
    CURSOR C2(v_isbn in varchar2) IS
        SELECT ANP.NODE_ID NODE_ID
        FROM  TABLE1 ANP,
            TABLE2 ANPP,
            TABLE3 AN
        WHERE ANP.NODE_ID=AN.ID AND

        CASE WHEN V_CATEGORY =11 THEN
        ANP.STRING_VALUE ='pdf' AND
        ANPP.STRING_VALUE ='product' AND

        CASE WHEN V_CATEGORY =10 THEN 
        ANP.STRING_VALUE ='IMAGE' AND
        ANPP.STRING_VALUE ='product11' AND
        END CASE
        ANP.TAME_ID=21 AND
            ANP.NODE_ID=v_isbn;
    BEGIN
    --Iterating all Products
    FOR R1 IN C1 
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        --To check whether Product is exists or not
        SELECT AN.ID INTO V_NODE_ID 
        FROM TABLE1 AN,
            TABLE2 ANP
        WHERE AN.ID=ANP.NODE_ID 
        AND ANP.STRING_VALUE in(R1.ISBN);

      FOR R2 IN C2(R1.ISBN) 
      LOOP
         ....  
      END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
       WHEN  NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT NOT FOUND.....'|| R1.ISBN);
    END;
  END LOOP;--looping gt_isbns
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proper `JOIN ON` syntax rather than the obsolete `tablea, tableb` syntax for `JOINS`. Your cursor query is equivalent to

```
CURSOR C2(v_isbn in varchar2) IS


SELECT anp.node_id node_id
FROM table1 anp
INNER JOIN table3 an ON anp.node_id = an.id
CROSS JOIN table2 anpp
WHERE (
        CASE 
            WHEN v_category = 11
                AND anp.string_value = 'pdf'
                AND anpp.string_value = 'product'
                THEN 1
            WHEN v_category = 10
                AND anp.string_value = 'IMAGE'
                AND anpp.string_value = 'product11'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) = 1
    AND anp.tame_id = 21
    AND anp.node_id = v_isbn;
```

I don't see any  column to  join between `table2`( `ANPP`) and other tables in your query. I assume it should be a cross join. If not, include proper join conditions for `ANPP` with other tables and remove the `CROSS` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause in cursor - means SQL language (the cursor is defined in a PL/SQL block, but the cursor definition is a plain SQL `SELECT` statement). `CASE` **statement** is only valid in PL/SQL; plain SQL does not have `CASE` statements, only `CASE` expressions.

You didn't tell us what the code is supposed to do, so I am not even going to read all of it (no way to know if it is correct without knowing what it is supposed to do). However, I understand what your attempt means (whether you wanted it to mean that or not), and I can show you how to achieve the same in a `WHERE` clause.

It seems, if `v_category = 11`, you want to require that `anp.string_value = 'pdf' and annp.string_value = 'product'`; but if `v_category = 10` you want to require different values. And, importantly, you didn't tell us what should happen when `v_category` is neither 11 nor 10 (in particular, if it is null). So you will have to edit the code so it does the right thing in those cases.

In any case - the `WHERE` clause may look something like this:

```
WHERE .....
  and anp.string_value  = case v_category when 11 then 'pdf'
                                          when 10 then 'IMAGE'     [else ...?] end
  and annp.string_value = case v_category when 11 then 'product'
                                          when 10 then 'product11' [else ...?] end
```